# Login to facebook in android app and pull down friends listing. How do i get accessToken?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having trouble not knowing where to get my AccessToken after logging into facebook from my android app. The code below is what I use to log in and it seems to work. But when I want to get a listing of friends, I don't know where to find the access token.

This is my subset of the code that logs in (from Facebook's developer site).

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Canceled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Error: %s", exception.toString()));
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

This is the part I want to use to get my list.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
    accessToken,
    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(
               JSONObject object,
               GraphResponse response) {
            // Application code
        }
    });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

How do I set the variable **accessToken**?
Are there any good examples of simple ways to do this out there? Everything I find seems very complicated for my level and not using a newer sdk (4.1.2 is what I have) but something old that seems to be depricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some changes in `Facebook SDK v.4` such as:

- Session Removed - AccessToken, LoginManager and CallbackManager
  classes supercede and replace functionality in the Session class.
- Access Tokens - Briefly, you can load `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken` with
  the SDK from cache or if the app is cold launched from an app
  bookmark. For instructions, see [Facebook Login for Android, Get

  Current Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#get_current).

But you also need to write some code as described in the link.

Answer (score 1):

After Login use this code to get Friend List of those friend who are using this app.

> Now Facebook does not provide the whole list of friend.

```
GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphJSONArrayCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONArray objects, GraphResponse response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try 
                    {
                        Log.d("Garph Friend ", objects.toString(2));
                        friendCallback(objects.toString(2));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).executeAndWait();
```